# Why does log log/ log/* log/** work the same in gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWj4x.png)
log log/ log/* log/** should work differently in gitignore,But you can see that they are doing the same thing. Why is that

I think log and log/ should not ignore its subdirectories and files.
log/* should not ignore files in its subdirectories.
log/** is going to ignore everything in it.

Comment: By definition if you ignore a directory you are also ignoring everything inside it. The same logic applies that if you ignore a file you are ignoring all text inside it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please replace your image link by a brief backtick(`\``)-formatted sketch of your directory structure? On this site, images are dispreferred. If you format the question using text to the extent possible, other people will be able to find your question more easily.